# php select value every 4 for pagination mysql Keysets

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, optimization, crystal-reports

I am working on pagination and its slow for large results. So I am trying to get the page values on every 4 results to use as the foundation. but I don't have any idea on how to get it to work.

This is what I want to get working

example table:

> price | ID 
>  12     | 1   <- start of Page
>   1
>  352   | 2
>  66     | 3
>   
>  33     | 4   
>   12     | 5   <- Start of page 2
>   120   | 6
>   2       | 7
>  3123 | 8
>   122   | 9   <- Start of page 3
>  4523 | 10
>  9823 |
>   11

I want to be able to get the page number vales as `(122,9)` for page 3 and pass it to MySQL query when the 3nd page is clicked on  `[1] [2] 3 [4]`.....

using "`SELECT * FROM data WHERE (price, id) > ($price_value, $id_value) AND (car = '$car') AND LIMIT 4`" echo results with while() to get results from `ID 9 - 12` etc.

Comment: Is it MySql or MS SQL Server, tag correctly?

Comment: MySQL Server on xampp

Comment: You can do LIMIT 0,4; or LIMIT 4,8; etc Limit can take two parameters. Also you have to know your total count to do pagination.

Comment: I know limit method but its way to slow for large databases. I need a faster method using (price, id) > ($price_value, $id_value)

Comment: Couldnt understand is it a crystal report reauirement

Comment: How big is your table ? Did you check your indexes ?

Comment: sorry I am not sure what you mean with "crystal report reauirement" ?

Comment: I have index working. its a DB of over > 100,000 with random stuff. it takes to long when going to the last page. first few pages are great and fast. but Limit has its limitations on speed over a few pages.

Comment: are you running crystal reports and going through pages in preview tab?

Comment: no I am not running it

Answer (score 1):

Pagination is not a performance problem if you do not use `OFFSET`, but instead "remember where you left off".  [My blog on pagination](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) discusses the problem and solution.